# Атрибуты sizes и srcset в элементе img

Tags: html, css

У элемента `<img>` есть атрибуты `sizes` и `srcset`, пытаюсь разобраться и понять, как они работают, но, кажется, в [этом примере](http://htmlreference.io/element/img/) они у меня не работают, хотя вроде бы с поддержкой в хроме проблем не должно быть.

Объясните доступно, пожалуйста, принцип их работы.

Comment: [Хорошая статья про responsive изображения (en)](http://responsiveimages.org/), [sizes поддерживаются многими браузерами](https://caniuse.com/#search=sizes)

Answer (score 1):

Атрибут `sizes` не поддерживается ни в одном браузере. Атрибута `imgset` вообще не существует. Для указания картинок высокого разрешения используйте атрибут `srcset`:

```
  <picture>
   <source srcset="image/mushroom_landscape.jpg, image/mushroom_retina.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 60em)">
   <img src="image/mushroom.jpg" alt="">
  </picture>
```

Атрибут `srcset` имеет эффект только тогда, когда элемент `<source>` располагается непосредственно внутри элемента `<picture>`.

Каждая строка может состоять их следующих частей:

1. адрес изображения;
2. дескриптор ширины, который представляет собой целое положительное
   число, за которым следует w (например: 600w). Дескриптор
   подсказывает браузеру, для какой контрольной точки использовать
   данное изображение;
3. дескриптор плотности пикселей, представляет собой положительное
   десятичное число, за которым сразу следует х.

Каждая строка в списке должна содержать по крайней мере дескриптор ширины или плотности пикселей.

Браузер выбирает наиболее подходящее изображение для отображения в данный момент времени.

Comment: Я не уверен, что дескриптор ширины работает.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста, показать рабочие примеры, а не справочную информацию?

Answer (score 0):

У меня так заработало

```html
<picture>
  <source  media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="2.jpg">
  <source  media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="1.jpg">
  <img src="def.jpg" alt="A very exciting yacht race.">
</picture>
```